# Select all products using API - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, api

how can i select all products and one product by his SKU?
Line 23.

**`$serviceArgs = ["sku" => 'SKU'];`**

```
function getAuthToken($hostname, $username, $password)
    {
      $wsdlUrl = "http://$hostname/soap/default?wsdl=1&services=integrationAdminTokenServiceV1";
      $soapClient = new SoapClient($wsdlUrl, ['soap_version' => SOAP_1_2]);
      $serviceArgs = ['username' => $username, 'password' => $password];
      $response = $soapClient->integrationAdminTokenServiceV1CreateAdminAccessToken($serviceArgs);
      return $response->result;
    }

    $token = getAuthToken($hostname, $username, $password);
    $opts = [
      'http'=> [
          'header' => 'Authorization: Bearer ' . $token
      ]
    ];
    $wsdlUrl = "http://$hostname/soap/default?wsdl=1&services=catalogProductRepositoryV1";

    $serviceArgs = ["sku" => 'SKU'];

    $context = stream_context_create($opts);

    $soapClient = new SoapClient($wsdlUrl, array(
      'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
      'stream_context' => $context
    ));

    $response = $soapClient->catalogProductRepositoryV1Get($serviceArgs);

    print_r ($response);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$tokenUrl = 'https://example.com/soap/default?wsdl&services=integrationAdminTokenServiceV1';
$catalogProductRepositoryUrl = 'https://example.com/soap/default?wsdl&services=catalogProductRepositoryV1';

$username = 'MyUsername';
$password = 'MyPassword';
$options = [
    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
    'trace' => 1,
    'connection_timeout' => 120,
];

$soapClient = new SoapClient($tokenUrl, $options);
$response = $soapClient->integrationAdminTokenServiceV1CreateAdminAccessToken([
    'username' => $username,
    'password' => $password
]);

$token = $response->result;

// create bearer token Authorization header
$options['stream_context'] = stream_context_create([
    'http' => [
        'header' => sprintf('Authorization: Bearer %s', $token)
    ]
]);

// get product with sku 24-MB04
$soapClient = new SoapClient($catalogProductRepositoryUrl, $options);
$response = $soapClient->catalogProductRepositoryV1Get(['sku' => '24-MB04']);
$result = $response->result;
$productName = $result->name; //Strive Shoulder Pack


// get all products or use filters on collection
$searchCriteria = [
    'searchCriteria' => [
        'filterGroups' => [
            [
                /*'filters' => [
                    [
                        'field' => 'sku',
                        'value' => '24-MB04',
                        'condition_type' => 'eq',
                    ],
                ],*/
            ],
        ],
        //'current_page' => 1,
        //'page_size' => 2,
    ],
];

$soapClient = new SoapClient($catalogProductRepositoryUrl, $options);
$response = $soapClient->catalogProductRepositoryV1GetList($searchCriteria);
$result = $response->result;
$items = $result->items;
$total = $result->totalCount;
```

You can also check `dev/tests/api-functional/testsuite` files for more examples

UPD: and example how to get all products

```
$soapTokenUri = 'https://example.com/soap/default?wsdl&services=integrationAdminTokenServiceV1';
$catalogProductRepositoryUrl = 'https://example.com/soap/default?wsdl&services=catalogProductRepositoryV1';

$username = 'MyUsername';
$password = 'MyPassword';
$options = [
    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
    'trace' => 1,
    'connection_timeout' => 120,
];

$soapClient = new SoapClient($soapTokenUri, $options);
$response = $soapClient->integrationAdminTokenServiceV1CreateAdminAccessToken([
    'username' => $username,
    'password' => $password
]);

$token = $response->result;

// create bearer token Authorization header
$options['stream_context'] = stream_context_create([
    'http' => [
        'header' => 'Authorization: Bearer ' . $token
    ]
]);

// get all products or use filters on collection
$searchCriteria = [
    'searchCriteria' => [
        'filterGroups' => [[]],
    ],
];

$soapClient = new SoapClient($catalogProductRepositoryUrl, $options);
$response = $soapClient->catalogProductRepositoryV1GetList($searchCriteria);
$result = $response->result;
$items = $result->items;
$total = $result->totalCount;
var_dump($items);
```

Comment: Sorry, I not uderstand code. How can i select all products?

Comment: with `catalogProductRepositoryV1GetList` method and `searchCriteria` with empty `filterGroups`.  Try last block from my example

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] SoapClient::SoapClient(): 'uri' option is required in nonWSDL mode in /public_html/folder/file.php:89 Stack trace: #0 /public_html/folder/file.php(89): SoapClient->SoapClient(NULL, Array) #1 {main} thrown in /public_html/folder/file.php on line 89

Comment: updated the answer